# RegisterWaitForSingleObjectEx() & several SetEvent()

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I find a tricky behavior of multiple `SetEvent`s with `RegisterWaitForSingleObjectEx()`.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Threading;

VOID CALLBACK Callback(PVOID lpParameter, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    String^ string = gcnew String("");

    Monitor::Enter(string->GetType());

    //wait for 2 seconds
    for(int i=1; i<=2;i++) {
        Sleep(1000);
        cout << i << " seconds \n";
    }

    Monitor::Exit(string->GetType());
}


void main()
{

     HANDLE eventhandle = CreateEvent( 
     NULL,               // default security attributes
     FALSE,              // manual-reset event
     FALSE,              // initial state is nonsignaled
     TEXT("WriteEvent")  // object name
    ); 

    //register the callback for the event
    RegisterWaitForSingleObjectEx(eventhandle, Callback, nullptr, -1, WT_EXECUTELONGFUNCTION);

    BOOL bEvented[3];
    bEvented[0] = SetEvent(eventhandle);
    //Sleep(10);
    bEvented[1] = SetEvent(eventhandle);
    //Sleep(10);
    bEvented[2] = SetEvent(eventhandle);
    cout << "event0 = " << bEvented[0] << ", event1 = " << bEvented[1] << ", event2 = " << bEvented[2] << " \n";

}
```

I set the Event 3 times. So, I expect the callback to be called 3 times (please correct me if I am wrong). 
But I get only 2 callbacks.

If I uncomment the lines `//Sleep(10);` , I get 3 callbacks.
What is happening here?

I am using Win7 64bit

**UPDATE:**

Can you please give an example about how to achieve this using semaphore?

**Actual scenario:**

I have a third-party library where I have to register a HANDLE to get notified about the occurrence of an event. Most of the times, I am able to get the notification (signalling on the HANDLE). Sometimes, I am not getting the correct "number of signalling", as expected.

I am passing the HANDLE created using `CreateEvent()` and registered a callback for the HANDLE using `RegisterWaitForSingleObjectEx()`.

I suspect that this race condition is the reason for the behavior.

How to overcome this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Martin: I was editing. You are lightening fast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetEvent` on an event that's already signalled is a no-op. You have a race condition between the main thread that calls `SetEvent`, and the worker thread that waits on it (and resets it automatically when the wait is satisfied).

Most likely, you manage to call `SetEvent` twice while the worker is still running the first callback.

Comment: Yup - was just about to post that, so +1 for typing faster:)  OP - if you want to ensure that the callback runs exactly as many times as you signal, why are you using an event instead of a semaphore?

Comment: In my understanding, when the `SetEvent` is called, a worker thread is dispatched to do the callback work. So Calling `SetEvent` 3 times should queue 3 threads. Is this understanding wrong?

Comment: Calling `SetEvent` simply signals the event (if it wasn't already) - nothing more, nothing less. Somewhere, there may (or may not) be a worker thread sitting blocked on `WaitForSingleObject` waiting for this  event to be signalled; once it is, that thread goes through and executes the callback. But if you signal the event while no one's waiting on it - whether once or 10 times - then nothing happens until some thread gets to call `WaitForSingleObject` again (at which point it goes through immediately, since the event is already signalled).